How to check if drive is bottleneck to video playing performance
My computer was working fine till recently, when I swapped my 256Gb SSD OS drive (win10) to a cheap 1 Tb SSD drive (both laptop M2 PCIe connector). I used DiskGenius copy system function to copy the drive and when I compared the files on both drives it seemed it did a perfect job.
I often watch Youtube videos at 3x or 4x speeds (here's a great addon for that). But now, Firefox is freezing and I can barely use it at 2.5 speed, other apps will also then freeze or become sluggish.
There were only 2 changes I can think of: Firefox update or my disk swap. Looking at Windows taskmgr, it tells me the CPU and GPU are working at ~30%. The disk I/O rate is also very low. The "Avg. Disk Queue Length" is also low (<0.15) in perfmon. I tried watching Youtube in a private/incognito window (which should mostly run the browser on RAM), but it made no difference, the browser would again freeze. HWiNFO also didn't highlight any problems with the disk.
Question: how can I check if my new, cheap SSD drive is bottling the performance of the browser when watching Youtube videos at high speeds?
Related:

How do I know if my drive is a bottleneck?
Difficulty investigating faulty hardware


Perform a random write test using the utility of your choice, for instance, I heard CrystalDiskMark might do something like that. You could also provide the specifications of each disk.

It is somewhat unlikely your SSD is the issue, What happens if you try a different browser?  Also, what OS do you use ( which may be relevant to posters who advise tests).

Rereading your post - I wonder if its a plugin issue. That polyspeed plugin seems to be very niche...

I'm starting to think it's a Firefox issue, but it might be something with the plugin. I also rebooted my computer a few times, it did seem to help! One issue is that I often put my computer to sleep instead of powering it off and on. Sleeping isn't good, Windows10 doesn't wake up well. It might as well be from other programs, I often do 10 things at the same time. I don't think it's temperature related, but it might be. CrystalDiskMark didn't show anything unusual, besides the SSD I mentioned I only have an external HDD, with few accesses. Brave also sometimes freezes

It won't hurt to run a "CHKDSK/f" by running command prompt as administrator and then tell the response to check disk at next startup. Then do a restart and let the computer check for possible corruption from the data transfer.
CrystalDiskMark was a good suggestion, but you should run that on the old HDD and compare it to the new HDD as well. Another piece of software that I'd suggest you use for the comparison is HD Tune.
https://www.hdtune.com/
Although, I'm leaning to possibly the issue being with the new SSD and it quality. Possibly might be best to get a higher quality SSD even though it might cost a little more.
Also, is there any new firmware update for the SSD? Sometimes manufacturers release these and might help.

I did a chkdsk, but there were no errors (also did sfc /scannow just to be safe). I'm starting to think it might be the RAM, but I don't know why it didn't show up before. This is very odd, but now seems to be better when I have fewer apps on. And no new firmware AFAIK

But the issue didn’t happen on the old HDD so I wouldn’t suspect it could be bad RAM unless you touched the RAM and caused it damage. I know you shouldn’t really defrag an SSD, but try following the advice from this site (but don’t set a schedule to defrag your SSD, just defrag manually once): https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/optimize-ssd-in-windows

defrag wouldn't make a difference. I'm wondering if it could be a driver issue... this could make a lot of sense, if new drivers were needed, but the old ones were being used

In my career, I've never had an issue or needed to install a HDD driver. I doubt that would help. I'm still leaning to replacing the HDD with a more well known brand/higher quality HDD. It's also possible that you got a lemon or there are issues with the SSD.
